# Store the result of (Unit * Price) as Total to Table

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 tables. TblToy and Tbl2Toy

```
 TblToy
 TID   TName   TUnit   TPrice
 1     Robot   5       10   
 2     Doll    10      5     

 Tbl2Toy
 TID   TName   Total
 1     Robot        
 2     Doll
```

This is the code.

```
 Create proc ProTotal (@TID int)
 as
 begin
 select TID, TName, TUnit, Price, TUnit * Price as Total
 from TblToy
 where TID = @TID
 end
 go

 Exec ProTotal 1
```

Result

```
 TID   TName   TUnit   TPrice   Total
 1     Robot   5       10       50
```

I want to store the total price of the robot to Tbl2Toy Total.

Comment: Tbl2Toy is already created with data and you need to update the Total column?

Comment: Just `drop table Tbl2Toy`. TblToy is enough. :)

Comment: Are you wanting to store the data or just display it in a query?

Comment: I want to put the total of unit * price to Tbl2Toy Total. Is it possible?

Comment: Like get that total to Tbl2Toy Total.

Comment: yes I want to store the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As has been mentioned, you don't really need the second table. But if you do want to do it that way, plug this into your stored proc instead of the SELECT statement.

```
 UPDATE     T2
 SET        T2.Total = T1.TUnit * T1.Price
 FROM       Tbl2Toy AS T2
 INNER JOIN TblToy AS T1 ON T1.TID   = T2.TID
 WHERE      T2.TID = @TID
```

Comment: Thank a lot ! This is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I would not store it but create a view for this

```
create view vwToy as
  select TID, TName, TUnit, TPrice, TUnit * TPrice as Total
  from   tblToy
```

then you can do :

```
select * from vwToy
```

which would give you

```
TID   TName   TUnit   TPrice   Total
1     Robot   5       10       50
2     Doll    10      5        50
```

or if you want a specific toy only :

```
select * from vwToy where TID = 1
```

which would give you

```
TID   TName   TUnit   TPrice   Total
1     Robot   5       10       50
```

Comment: My goal is to store it. But Thank for your answer !

Comment: storing info that can be calculated is not always good idea, why do you want to store it

Comment: It's something that my instructor had asked me, so I kinda didn't know how to store it that's why I came to ask.

Comment: but you do realize that when a value changes in TUnit or TPrice you have to loop through all stored values and adjust them right ? You will have to do that each time a value changes. By calculating the values you never ever need to change anything anymore and still have always correct totals. Its up to you

Answer (score 0):

I think you can omit the stored procedure and accomplish what you want with a [MERGE](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/merge-transact-sql) statement.

```
MERGE TblToy2 AS target
USING (SELECT * FROM TblToy) AS source
ON (target.TID = source.TID)
WHEN MATCHED
    THEN UPDATE SET target.TOTAL = source.TUnit * source.TPrice;
GO
```

Comment: It affected all the rows. But this really helps me a lot thank a bunch !